Access values of design variables while solver is running (OpenMDAO with IPOPT)
I'm trying to do trajectory optimisation in Dymos (a library built atop OpenMDAO), but I'm not getting the convergence properties I'm expecting and I'd like to inspect the intermediate solutions of the solver in order to debug.
Is there a way, in OpenMDAO, to access the design variables as the solver is running, so that intermediate values can be printed or plotted? I believe this is theoretically possible as other libraries seem to provide this functionality for IPOPT (see the bottom of this page: https://cyipopt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#scipy-compatible-interface), but I can't work out how to do this (or see any documentation) in OpenMDAO.

One solution would be to enable the Driver's "debug_print" option.  This will print the design variables at every iteration:
Debugging Drivers
Another option would be to add a recorder to the driver, so that the design variables, constraints, and objectives are recorded at each iteration.  There are also options to enable the recording of other inputs and outputs in the model.
Advanced Case Recording

Thank you - this is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't realise that the information would be saved in a database which could be queried while the solver is running - a very nice implementation!

I've implemented this but I'm still a little stuck. I assumed I would need to plot the driver values but the number of these stays constant (and doesn't seem to correspond at all to the number of solver iterations), but the solver values don't seem to correspond either. Which should I be plotting if I want the design variables on each iteration of the solver (IPOPT), scaled to their real-life values? Many thanks for any assistance.

So the Driver recorder records a "case" each time the driver evaluates the model. This doesn't necessary correspond to the number of major iterations, depending on the specific optimizer and what its doing.
You'll need to loop through the cases and pick out the variables you want to see,.  Does the documentation here help?  https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/latest/features/recording/case_reader.html#accessing-cases-using-get-case-method
